# What is a uninitialized reference variable when it's not null

Tags: java, variables

In java, local reference variables do not have a default value of null before they are initialized. 
What exactly is the difference between a variable with a value of null, and a variable with no value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An uninitialized reference doesn't have no value, it has an undefined value (and the compiler prevents you from using them, IIRC).  A reference initialized to `null` will result in a equality comparison with `null` always evaluating to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

In a less-restrictive language a variable that has not been somehow initialized can contain random data.

In Java an uninitialized variable cannot be referenced.  This is enforced by both the compiler and the bytecode verifier.